# How to select the row before lastrow in a pivottable?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I need to **select a cell one row before the lastrow**. How do i do that?

I have tried `lastrow = lastrow -1` and it apparently doesn't work that way.

```vb
Set pt = .PivotTables("PivotTable2")
lastrow = .Range(Split(pt.TableRange1.Address(0, 0), ":")(1)).Row
```

I just need to select the cell one row before the last row in column F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the Job:

```
Set pt = .PivotTables("PivotTable2")

Dim lstr() As String

lstr = Split(pt.RowRange.Address, ":")

.Range(lstr(1)).Offset(-1, 0).Select
```

`pt.RowRange` gives you the rows on which the Pivot Table `pt` exists.

Comment: there is an error on this line `.Range(lastrow(1)).Offset(-1, 0).Select`. it says **Expected array**

Comment: You must have used `Dim lasrow As Integer`, remove that line and add `Dim lastrow()  As String`

Comment: @HarvintRaj , either make changes according to the previous comment or use the amended code in Answer

Answer (score 0):

You can `Offset` the first row of the `PivotTable.TableRange` to get its last row:

```
lastrow = pt.TableRange1.Rows(1).Offset(pt.TableRange1.Rows.Count - 1).Row
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow - 1, "F").Select
```